# How to create shortcut to run Selenium script?

Tags: selenium, browser-automation

Is it possible to have some kind of shortcut (probably bookmarklet) to run specific Selenium script?

While developing webapp I'd like to have a possibility to quickly run specific Selenium script to log in and navigate to specific page. I'd like to avoid having yet another (Selenium in this case) window opened just for this.

Also, it's a little surprising this hasn't been raised at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list

In [Keyboard shortcut for opening Selenium IDE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/selenium-users/group%3aselenium-users%2420AND%2420subject%3ashortcut/selenium-users/yoGJ5x655ug) thread on Selenium Users group one finds this fragment:

```
<menuitem label="Selenium IDE" oncommand="SeleniumIDE.Loader.openRecorder();" insertbefore="sanitizeSeparator,prefSep" *accesskey="N"* />
```

which would suggest `SeleniumIDE.Loader`could be of some use here.

Comment: The answer is probably 'no' but can you explain more about why you would wants this and what problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: So you'd like to use Selenium not so much for its automated testing, but just as a macro to navigate to common pages?

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, indeed.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost No, usage of selenium is certainly on topic here (Selenium was merged into SQA pre beta) I just want to make sure we're on the same page as to your use-case.

Comment: Have you looked at GreaseMonkey ? http://www.greasespot.net/

Comment: Related:[How do I launch the Selenium IDE from the command line with a specific test case loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1144744/95735)

Answer (score 2):

Currently (to the best of my knowledge), Selenium does not have the ability to do this in the same window as you are already in, it must spawn it's own.

You may want to look into something like [WATiR](http://watir.com/) (ruby), [WatiN](http://watin.org/) (.NET), or iMacros ([firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/)) ([chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp))

If you just want to be able to run the navigation without the window being visible, try taking a look through this [discussion thread](http://www.seleniumwebdriver.com/google-selenium-webdriver/hide-browser-window/).

Comment: I don't object Selenium opening its own window as long as I don't see it :) Thanks for links. I would like to use Selenium as I already use it for some tests but it looks like yet another tool is needed, indeed.

Comment: I believe that you can.  Will edit answer.